# Grabbing ID Field from Element jQuery Each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom

I'm trying to cycle through all of the children in a `<ul>` list, assign an `onclick` event listener and use the ID of the element for that event.  I am using jQuery and jQueryMobile in my application.  For some reason, the ID property of the element always shows up blank?  When I alert the actual element, I get `[ObjectHTMLLIElement]`.  When I use the DevTools, the ID field is present in all of the Elements?

This is the ListView

This is how I am trying to accomplish this...

```
function set_onclicks()
{
    var count = $('#main-listview').children().length;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        $('#main-listview').children().each(function() {
            this.onclick = function() {
                project_id = this.id;
                $.mobile.changePage('#main-project-page', 'slide', true, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction and help explain why I cannot grab the ID?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

**Recent Edits**

I have tried implementing this, now that I know I do not need to bind through the `.each()` loop.

```
$('#main-listview').children().click(function() {
    alert(this);
    alert(this.id);
    project_id = this.id;
    $.mobile.changePage('#main-project-page', 'slide', true, true);
});
```

The first alert gives me `[ object HTTMLLIElement ]` the next alert gives me a blank...?

**EDIT 2 - HTML Example**
I think I know why now.  jQueryMobile is adding some `<div>` elements before it adds an `<a>` link.  Now, I am going to have to figure out how to get around this..

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="a" id="main-listview" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-first-child ui-btn-up-a">
        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
            <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a id="51e0278f2a1cb33a08000002" class="ui-link-inherit">123456 - The Project</a>
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $(this).attr('id') actually :)

Comment: @Vogel612 - I receive `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'attr' main.js:407
onclick`

Comment: i think that in your case this refers to the global object, not the current element

Comment: Don't just copy what people say before you understand it...

Comment: @Virus721 - If I understood what was supposed to happen, I wouldn't be here asking for help.  If it actually worked, I would then figure out why it worked...

Comment: Could you show an example of your html? I think bipen's answer should've worked for what you're describing, but maybe there's something else you haven't mentioned yet...

Comment: this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ACH9B/ - updated.

Comment: @Omar - You are my hero.  Thanks! That example was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have no idea why you are using function to set the click event.. (**and no need to use loop `$.each` to set the click event for each elements**).

just this should work

```
  $('#main-listview').children().click(function() {
             project_id = this.id;
            $.mobile.changePage('#main-project-page', 'slide', true, true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could do `children().click()` to set event handlers for all of the children.  I am still learning JavaScript and jQuery stuff.

Comment: Nope.  I tried adding an alert to `this` and an alert for `this.id` - 
I get `[ object HTMLLIElement ]` and then the next alert is completely blank?

Comment: It's because jQueryMobile is wrapping the `<a>` with a lot of other children I didn't know where getting loaded.  Thanks for continual help on my questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `this` in javascript event handler which you can not unless you bind it by `jQuery` object

Change

```
this.onclick = function() {
            project_id = this.id;
            $.mobile.changePage('#main-project-page', 'slide', true, true);
        }
```

To

```
$(this).click( function() {
            project_id = this.id;
            $.mobile.changePage('#main-project-page', 'slide', true, true);
});
```

**Simple solution** You do not have to check if elements are returned by selector before bind, thanks to jquery, made life easy and you do not need to use each for binding event.

```
$('#main-listview').click(function() {           
   project_id = this.id;
   $.mobile.changePage('#main-project-page', 'slide', true, true);          
});
```

Comment: `#main-listview` is the `<ul>` container, not the actual element that is being clicked on...  Still returns a blank when I `alert(this.id);`